# 1st Ansible Program - Errors on storing output to a file

Tags: networking, ansible

I wrote my first ansible program and trying to output a file to a new location on my linux box.  Failing at the syntax probably.  I would like the output of the file (show version) to dump into a new a file.  Here's the code I am using.  Is this the right syntax on copy/content section??:

vi test2-playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  tasks:
   - name: run show version on ios device
     ios_command:
       commands:
         - show version
       host: rf3.cor.las.ss34.net
       username: cisco
       password: cisco

     register: show_output

   - name: show output
     debug:
        var: show_output

   - name: display to a file in new folder
     copy: content = "{{show_output}}" dst= "/home/hellow/test1/rf3.cor.las.txt"
```

=====================

Runs the file but gives below error on display task:

}

```
TASK [display to a file] *******************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "src (or content) and dest are required"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/tmalhotra/Ansible_learning/test2-playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   

[tmalhotra@lasssnpr01net01 Ansible_learning]$
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is clearly stated in the error message:

`src (or content) and dest are required`

Your task contains a `content` parameter, but the destination parameter is incorrect (`dst` instead of `dest`)

Also, try using proper YAML in the last task:

```
$ ansible-playbook some.yml

PLAY [localhost]  ***************************************************************

TASK [display to a file in new folder] *****************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   

$ cat some.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: display to a file in new folder
      copy:
        content: "foo"
        dest: "/home/david/test.txt"
```